# Google Places API returning incomplete results if querying for type=establishment

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am having trouble getting the proper search results in Google's Places API. When querying for a given location for the type "restaurant", everything looks good and all nearby restaurants are shown. Yay! However, when querying with the type set to "establishment", some restaurants are missing (even though restaurants are tagged with type "establishment").

One example:

[Supreme Burger & Grill in Berlin (Google Maps Link)](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Supreme+Burger+Grill+%26+Bar/@52.5245804,13.3950217,20.63z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xca05bc8072f9c007)
Google Places API query for respective coordinates and **type=restaurant shows correctly Supreme Burger & Grill** as one of the first entries: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=52.524580,13.395186&type=restaurant&rankby=distance&key=API_KEY
Please note that in the response from the link above it is clearly shown that "Supreme Burger & Grill" is tagged with the following types: ["cafe","store","bar","restaurant","food","point_of_interest","establishment"]

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CpQCAQEAABd7vF3jDEnpBM063_3cK_mktrS4toa5t6OZZvIwB-QovA8SWDeoBNZUZWt0lUuGnCe1svJjnfoA9TMwUm01_599Ssys1783JDWx4-XEn7mTYPWnT51Wuqe0rcaj5dvKsFC-Q3RPC7cFF7abJLfThrNeaWzBfLT8PKt1ILYtWMJdDvJKWNCzQwCuc2vzUH9avS_jjiffh6Ssczt4f3qGptmAAByPqybTCUmgFOnOTFPvOlDfkQD6U0jagpD2Cp0t4dXI11UaUvCIMnxnStfj1d-J-5T04GHs6ihdrJZkb3X0Z5m7h5AEuM9OGQ0HucwPQYP0jYzD6Nku6rta79avrpsvgEDDa-3vt5EJLXiSx93XEhCNqo_LiUZ1XQPGsy98gwR9GhRqdxskzowtviExmK0aFHheSuIv_Q",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.5245804,
               "lng" : 13.3951888
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "1003d7ea1e0955dcb38831069222c48873512b51",
         "name" : "Rimon",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ_4u9t-dRqEcR0oGCwQGHZxw",
         "reference" : "CmRYAAAAUGLqSWZD8yaQzE6z1Z9fAWHBy-7E1-PH3v-ESnak6zzQDAFjvAy4wuxJngdIFut2SHQ024KBn0FJbiz2MByUhEQG2RT8__50rx4D6JOAR7VNFVvRGJs6ltdQqXV06MjeEhDtwHUp4It7BCQQExdixwhtGhTvQkRC8gDlbvM8frLB2vbBLyBC5A",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 26, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.5245804,
               "lng" : 13.3951888
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "9313980ba44271ffd33ad7d88e99ae3b78e0e2d9",
         "name" : "Supreme Burger Grill & Bar",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 3120,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104763774165454128791/photos\"\u003eJiří Syrový\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAmolcTt3hO1HH5sHxEgJQl1DqHw_6C-wNEu6mDlVDqLeIWC5X_EwqzE0Lu22g4LGJx3U-PXW2irNsmXZOPJMFks5rwafDtfTD4wwWw9iEwj90oP-mFto7WZgSk2sc8FIZEhBzEuaWT7UokN7BkbMX2oc0GhTEH63BiCK99ZBabGtxuoAe68-Q0A",
               "width" : 4160
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJvYy9t-dRqEcRB8D5coC8Bco",
         "rating" : 4,
         "reference" : "CnRuAAAAegUuQAZtuCQrFTRhR8ReCdYKeYqAxqbsXIQOB7YksugxKDbyk641KQO59JTqolOf-gYheEFH3k2IzjqjrHD2w2CJ3p10NQxgXq5YIYDM87AHgHlM2TeCoFQrV0v9f1kxTb_u3hVTr10hsJIWhkh6ohIQMBXVSb_6qCtrmA2odT6vsxoUpT3AL57_zxNWsdxc0aVjhY6JVl8",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "cafe",
            "store",
            "bar",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 26, Berlin"
      }, (...)
```

Google Places API query for respective coordinates and **type=establishment does NOT show "Supreme Burger & Grill" at all**: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=52.524580,13.395186&type=establishment&rankby=distance&key=API_KEY

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CpQCBAEAAHQrYHFSfGymsLIJp1NPHrlUUPGveGtfBmJbv0gwh8sCd7J0Fix8Hf_HuDeldYJ1anR5GECnhCIfc8NQwf6C90ylgRPx23Zo3M2c_vc8NtlTibhFHtdkpz9k1GGo6Kqbx8N_86aJ6FagmNwgxDr1CuySLMTXoJAiiC-HKoRZbmi9BqCmlWtOXf2KuIz6ClzkQHwYefXqOJm6pLMz9Og8e1MA5MPm2Qf_wK6zSCNI_XGLiK8qggXSvpQp0lGQxkOOzHVc4klaW_mpIPvsnstGz9rOYLwQCdZ7X6k0IVW3UdqYJDPpFV4dixFNe6KrITJ2siSrXGoIWmmmttD0ebmEFWJ_Xxfi1zYomL91Hcxvw4qUEhDYIcL9p__dgFYaRHHsLgCZGhQTHimHFgFDOVwuCn6qZXEf5gLpdA",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.5245804,
               "lng" : 13.3951888
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "3fd246ab90edf590f9145b5d9a5a987c0b586904",
         "name" : "Salzkommunikation Berlin GmbH",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 250,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104741993554463902002/photos\"\u003eSalzkommunikation Berlin GmbH\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAaJtalJt06jT0rZ7oKO1aeZ-D2PXYWuQVhShY_XEmiexbIIddbJQ4aDMvkwtlVsH4P_EqPuTJuc0NsdWoOlQq4HYzXMV_7KPbgSwS-T3Q0y_iwjI7yQl4pc6ue8L3IJUjEhC5kLgVHHoIAkfDUrB1ONQMGhQEE3mfdh7Xp6cNugcNT4Ja3BTbmw",
               "width" : 250
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ_4u9t-dRqEcRz1zvKXnL4vA",
         "reference" : "CoQBcQAAAFYTGL3AbX-3mM69VvXKiXA473eHTd-583ThBIOAlGyLy83M-_1d4es2sQJBhGiejxLKs5aLa8M0EZ8tde2WP9UmgsP8Blydy6RiFXA7cuACTXuJxP2JcEmze8vhIKj3IUGCaK9WPYVfBz6qWMPCRItkDP6xiAr9qvPobTHA_gXKEhCmOCnQow27wfVH7bRT9Ps5GhT_A-M50rAr5w_q61j3xQbWfzqhRg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 26, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52464,
               "lng" : 13.39503
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "38e0bdeedfba66b255737af93d72985d8898ce4d",
         "name" : "Galerie Kühn",
         "place_id" : "ChIJRaooyOdRqEcRweEAKPRvso8",
         "reference" : "CnRhAAAAtyuhpE4S9aCrPB9T_6hq4CJBktA_SUy6ia9PotuP8OLRV2tpnevCo-FDgXcBG_J9SNIItltjbHlKc3ZOnvRQSy_FtRXlqBgr89GYwWu8CcCOVqihB3TLrglFWo69utymbBAYiYaW_4lZXMZcZ_4Y6hIQTL0zVztyjwr-V4iDW7dWWhoUdELgs2jYK42vLcvEiUZIGQ5sjaU",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "art_gallery", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52464,
               "lng" : 13.39503
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "07fe6fad6a4a494e9a62dfee28dc916554d42fca",
         "name" : "Kunsthof Berlin",
         "place_id" : "ChIJhRZoXuhRqEcR8XUgfQt9uM8",
         "reference" : "CnRjAAAArQ-cgjrL8sZUHtA46GsXxwityxWi6hntGNJWX2fq1uPLCLjSKYaJsN6xwzIfIcpShKwEzVsgptS4jF6xPmylYW8fCZutdJRKB2wLHDnMDrOsjTUdVtw1CFtAg8ArI6vfOAhXcIWZHvefH0bBuNGkGRIQb69jqR9aJiJ3LNh3BZcdNBoUhsvnbl8WUPYGo11CsGD2PyWi2cs",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "art_gallery", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52464,
               "lng" : 13.39503
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "b8d67e442ba2e0ab572b88c8cd5d7fbe657375af",
         "name" : "Meditationszentrum Berlin Mitte",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 284,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108408315382431277282/photos\"\u003eMeditationszentrum Berlin Mitte\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAh08iyKsewwZFQKPCVnIXMYiUfP4tT8t_lUlPo-g3tL9Szy7rMk5bs3oVxVd1w_e6TjmaI9ucc_PvNRt-S-eFw75KVq-cNz7LGVUVMZiSAA7kES-AXXNvvT6EQjvlGkFtEhD70rW5H4NPUQo-u-XWXXxMGhRICFWAMhq0tT06dcgFyHZJtWAeRA",
               "width" : 600
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJC5_vDgROqEcRIY4MBSbzwHE",
         "reference" : "CoQBcgAAAEgKzS00ye-Z97m_Z1roT3wqkxNoVYr0Bh-AGFSWM2LUoid7TrdJ0H66HUXU4QDRBZggcxI7tZFmA6YDYHI4PomTEHZHl8DPrOwFMtB1nTMnoAgh83bvk7y9IhQwV5NtCtrenx499JxNyZcBVZGM4KKTNDhNmkl5ZxHh5sWlIXg2EhCmK0YdRWUTx_eQMxfviOAHGhRIi9K67QrAKCeSIARMw9Fnj6OqIg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "health", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52464,
               "lng" : 13.39503
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
         "id" : "7c24e6720bcdd1840aa7f5090b14f4d06a93368e",
         "name" : "Café Keksbank",
         "place_id" : "ChIJRaooyOdRqEcRInTc6Q0gqWU",
         "reference" : "CnRhAAAAB_2wTeOrnh5wGtSkva93hqvNLH2D_rW2jJZjBsBIJAhvsurByUqvTdyprLG07EKaXyZbmFasss2sYkRWDjcGDfmHDUMhY2n5S83vBoIqo1HeK4K8SJ_YVG5_17dDb7SSey02RNcG4PX2usDK7YaqNBIQAO0mAdygLyq8NKD7V64whhoUjy_Jq2zqSW9domemf8FeY8NQgdw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "cafe", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52464,
               "lng" : 13.39503
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "fc0dc53ac5ebd5223010fc2ddeee5604d8b7e2da",
         "name" : "Janosch Film & Medien AG",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJtfxmfDROqEcRJDp4wVcKLT4",
         "reference" : "CnRrAAAA46wS0obPhcRZegITchGq8VT_gthQ8Lh0Rk2_pmFkv_k-_X1KrnZcHkBYGSWOtwKySism28LRoMA3nUCpRtQ99vGmKWUK-HnHYy9E6DBN0uE3_l2mJgMPvcrzFjnErp6dwO_7FI80h-Iwd8OVOXg9KRIQHtfpJD8tTr_zD03CILcxOxoUavv3grs471N8SEdrG18FX7iWj4E",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52464,
               "lng" : 13.39503
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "32f8b4c9761cf5fcaf773ce06f32785b463a6fd3",
         "name" : "MEDITATIONSZENTRUM-BERLIN-MITTE",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 284,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106315129160590859585/photos\"\u003eMEDITATIONSZENTRUM-BERLIN-MITTE\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAFJHRdcmo-cxkm2aZMjy9xuzIQxOfPj7crb2Z1GPEsenw1HVyeIdgv23jlYRUcjiKpgTG0LpdxBy7GcR5q3uuZShVVSUoxYvi4SWzU6CiZ40T4p1vzqZE_JDnX0nJhKPoEhD9HCzdaNkuhdaMU-qZcmE9GhR3jyJM35mjGvSNp8gykzJ3I2ytDw",
               "width" : 600
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ74MVyOdRqEcRWdWdVNTb3aA",
         "reference" : "CoQBcwAAALJS7ejdcEZPGkvKNBhQRv67uEgcn-1jeOXWtavzRSdsa5vAdBpTTsuUgT9ba5mDTmxqSyB1efbkH1HlwN_zLNiGDiQJsebfc_s3c6yQCtSNwtWBuHWWuc13dnpDFo-5EcDTOqbnTWA1N_HTV9wv7bxrRy0Oh7V5cBLFJUHwBiqFEhBE5158c9Kcab8fZWKbfxzfGhRr53U26ruevzMS8vtqio688AsLtg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "health", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52464,
               "lng" : 13.39503
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "c9592a0d9a93cf0791ead47f06cf3ad4144e2ba7",
         "name" : "della Rovere 'Kunst im Pferdestall'",
         "place_id" : "ChIJRaooyOdRqEcRcXIC4SW50aE",
         "reference" : "CoQBdwAAAM2Z7wzgN2yIjnzNS6YEsItNX26szszKgF4hFXwhrplCVcmsBbXax8Gyi6r1kfpwXdorYgyd0kaaGcWJ9-aiOhVRreTu6n3HmI25SHn_LegUEqM0U0ERni04byFDVC6pyyOg7EDCm-0d9w8ntAtorxWbUilkvIZtL44o5ozebQQgEhCsWjJoSoWkJpraGM4o1DaOGhQFRVeRIW6xURD8nnsG6lTS7keIkA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "art_gallery", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52464,
               "lng" : 13.39503
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "5e88fe833efca16d3ee4e0cd30f069b2ef1be347",
         "name" : "LA RED GmbH",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1481,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117084969479154726287/photos\"\u003eLA RED GmbH\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAtDV9-V4_RwUhp8dXLck3T88jJAEz9emAQXwJOsxzQXHPDYQV-a4329oxikJcsAU5BIW9DgPAYEPoLI1hzoZ_tKO1rMjtkixGnyqMN_l_2dZRlSM-t2utGpgdDxDKvD4aEhDw57f2-4eLbP6KZt6KEacwGhQS9ERl05ZwxePI3DDeFix2LgV5gQ",
               "width" : 2048
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJbS-ByOdRqEcRUum_HKszcWk",
         "reference" : "CmReAAAAX3c4dgW2Hmb9ZNP566hbzxT4KFe5JWuxtcrUMkKEs86UKjYcARVzi3vuAUhVj9EqTPfp92wHZnnH-Xg5ffEuhdvYCaG70QiXgsDNaT36M_TxY4_ssT6IUoy22__2DacgEhAahqcaBYXQrgGmds21aNCkGhR4BgGDtl_zUG6xZh-mPVIU-PP9Aw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52462389999999,
               "lng" : 13.3949919
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
         "id" : "ab27cf1b2ad1eaf78e5fd27f12fbc7f7932f1253",
         "name" : "Café Galerie Poesie",
         "place_id" : "ChIJRaooyOdRqEcRTurWZGz4l4M",
         "reference" : "CnRoAAAAmTeTsFylai4n3TVtNa-5LDd4FwVWjYSP7lafvEixNICXV4wk3DxqS85C787eprFeGvf3qyfjXvNcuNKO9sg6WXbf3SvPGJdyE7iJt8Xf-eHmaxSt7gdJK6I7YLCj5x73raNrSaNHOP05WfKUZ-jDdRIQ1cl68bjt6dLD_gjf419LgBoUsTG1ZV667lxWFpBurb8ZetjW4uI",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "cafe", "art_gallery", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.524627,
               "lng" : 13.3949737
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "6ee78869f958f226dc9305bf7a2d42032c51cf08",
         "name" : "Que Pasa",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 480,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107917911173359693764/photos\"\u003eMexikanisches Restaurant Que Pasa Berlin\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAVN6WG0wXBD0aBOYTqYEdJQq4FfcOdYiNyRvo_Srn7wltAEBcOgnsCzebRE-djZ3-GtTV-w0zQaQAH-5n4IkE_gm7rcmp02WqddD9jWIc-PP7L-g2n6sQJz7AU00eheNFEhCl3UxJcj_j3Z7JnIzrtChqGhTLr-wzMZ42FoK1EgOvuyY8Lu9iqQ",
               "width" : 720
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJRaooyOdRqEcRACu8wXZnusc",
         "rating" : 3.7,
         "reference" : "CmRcAAAAiyPYHt9JP_PZNfvAzHqRR4aFYHqhXCBhyESNZ2TOEW2dEqYqdU3oudKKk3KMVnFe0VCS_oKIbJXBK6mRNBxksu6oo2AxTPzxY1-UmyMsr90ubtMmkKQ5otFgIeY9UnasEhBYCHvzXt03JPi6Tbil0T9pGhShw3i_mQJMItF7bbP1EjKJS9a8bQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 27, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.5246061,
               "lng" : 13.3949381
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "833664dc0f3bf940d7def0ae74f55b2c87434a0f",
         "name" : "pirminpartners Rechtsanwälte Fachkanzei für Baurecht Architektenrecht Immobilienrecht",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2048,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109169201103135674582/photos\"\u003epirminpartners Rechtsanwälte Fachkanzei für Baurecht Architektenrecht Immobilienrecht\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAf4IbCmS8wyx2CUixiNoKccbRw54GLmZMNmIn29wYu44YqKycRpXEyBEErFVcv9iVM-Sg9LI3Qwi-yccefG4cSRj4F_wGdHLAT7qgTA87JeGJNGK-cEsm5MO8jrGSbK6uEhAtS4C-JM2Lq3f2IWC6y-l9GhSeiRNmoU2PeU-fbsgeMu_DumRp-w",
               "width" : 1365
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ74MVyOdRqEcRHYib05xRqNU",
         "reference" : "CrQBrAAAAD4SjIw4d4vbNgCtjM_cltzGgJzoQpncS08JfpdahQP_XQAmYUAfWVVmJEVouj_MVCXX1Bjw0DxqK-TPaoGCoQLZhDcMiPkVn832bzadUZ3z_uNslEtwnrYERaA2uaOqyCiUXye_AT-75ma-5gZ0MAKrbKqaub3WMo-_nyfL-jrEzNdNwEdmz3OpBi0XIckwKJV8z5zzamVanukspbzAW8kS1rrFWdwuHHDEKYZiSxtIEhC0zaturt7ryiXEjsu1OiGWGhSkDXdr1VJGNRM0HtshMsNRp1mpzQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "lawyer", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Rosenthaler Straße 32, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52479,
               "lng" : 13.3956
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "23d6e94f96d3fdf10bf8be5e639356e9ce7eb5ae",
         "name" : "Longma 2 Thaimassage",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 494,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111889601485157837973/photos\"\u003eLongma 2 Thaimassage\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAz_XU7ufCv-1u_XIkXc6DJ9dUZx10xEuSFIGFh3jl9HpLWtquHEzeDXeWdidXFInwEQWDWdSeeUgmNatKV610CwjjWUHCFSi3DaxsG0ABislukUuXAqZZRlA7Fec5OyZQEhAI_zmsphIgv3dt0UfLv5-kGhTs9sSD9lyZd2xcShwdZElzU5_cGQ",
               "width" : 462
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ98ZHsedRqEcRHppjya_6LM4",
         "reference" : "CnRoAAAArdjw99B4kIsIu1TGUvhTdlhv3ynT0zn27vCAKpsrUKwP2MhQBnuoO3cn3kaLCQnZRFN6OadtRLQM-IoP3MqsXYMjy4sBeWsO0MEaYFF-IMt42MsHaqDiSi85GaH76YvYbpvb8joTrMYfhjJpW2kfEhIQodUaCY_3pdgJcvGu8gt95hoUBsqzEvNiTf4MihACPMx81SoJdxo",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "health", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Krausnickstraße 24, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.5247343,
               "lng" : 13.3946097
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "05b1d8cc8dcc844dfa9712c817a830ad262e237f",
         "name" : "Oren",
         "place_id" : "ChIJO6sqyedRqEcRtJZBXqXcZ2g",
         "reference" : "CmRXAAAA4YlHccYP72lSuVPACCUJtJBZpY09DsP7I8bS9xlY7w6C1h6-q0yb5PuzXn5aZYNeLoeIz8ToTs8uhZiXiS_NG-8366yBRzdiIkZs_hDqGv7vRUtqBRTIJSWPBSotzljlEhDM_kmcBoWUmWnBnfR3R6UTGhQaQTXLHe5yBASMhM0Ihsu8LZlwMQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 28, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.5245338,
               "lng" : 13.395812
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "0764a849cc1392059dd5f219971cd10d7353556a",
         "name" : "Gambrinus trifft Bacchus",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 600,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104746532787906547180/photos\"\u003eSlawek Kobylka\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAwPrYGEVp7_wIqH2vODEDZjnU68Ga9JNP1T_-UjjrRfflvyleOPgPdFlhgPENndhrwfEggAyCIcSSpXh8smO1Vz51Tfrez9K-MZ-0zRR8iwXpkNzRfaoSLO3nJk8IK2ngEhDRiD3qU2dJrEX_3ETud8q3GhQg_8ma4A4w-IR4HpEhewS0W5eqfQ",
               "width" : 800
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJwao4c-lRqEcR_VVfwLA_svg",
         "rating" : 3.9,
         "reference" : "CnRsAAAAwoinPY4BDOIcyC-7EVEQOoLnP30U155G0WkvWzZqHWRzbWzpFpyDvlmHSR940N-yVqNvQXcFf7eosYBpTG_H7gqppohiS4E_k8-fe-cbUF60ezzIlvCFvsNOcB03W219Qlx1b49IwX8INjweVKP1KhIQCrFCB48_Vi3LoI-liWPFaxoUYMerxwl0oEU5vTa8mXHGZUkcG_8",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Krausnickstraße 1, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52455,
               "lng" : 13.39584
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "cd298b4322f62d2d5f7372626cc5d4850e6fd910",
         "name" : "Strichmann",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ65ZIsOdRqEcR6KZ0QeIlfLA",
         "reference" : "CmReAAAACeV2wD51jfnNeAccnbrpcAYplo-8wnxuKg639Ygtk1timCVGhSFAl8NndptEfVN4FBTRT_7YZewNJW2SiKJHZPgdCUnNHAqHIG2n-WzA9Re-2g5FAQtGNPuB8LjA-oi-EhCjwpjes4zAWABv2ot99fgAGhR8FdaId0SxQEcP9DxgAxe9qHpHyQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Krausnickstraße 1, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52449,
               "lng" : 13.3959
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "66ef7751f324c451b6052339b52a9fcf447cc243",
         "name" : "Luccico",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 480,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106477419802646273594/photos\"\u003eLuccico\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAA2Vn-QjM7H5xlWy00m7f-2jFfS_ZEwxSlaigC-5YBpe1Ple009V05LhyPYxbYgv1xRGDT92FUIU1MOgXyUiJ15qUenHXPqh7mUW6FvBgWzWIjXPHR01rEM0UwTnWSrIzREhAA_1ZeXeJJYAykW03Tf4MqGhRI_Rs_uUFL_yMW0Z5CIe9dVmR7SA",
               "width" : 339
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ40XXpedRqEcR3MzpYp-_7_E",
         "reference" : "CmRbAAAAotmOK8cWggL6j4C6y1CnmZdjDf3b1YG6twiEy4me6266XMfxsbcbJeaZc1kZCRJOjovgTnu2H3hm_dR0KCdxma9hWp0amnILee_OL1MeqZXn1R1kkui94nQtwdlzSEmGEhD-RoPH1-sTCA6m7s36T8uzGhQGC0pJgDeNzgafmU5wDmpdvYTtvw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "shoe_store", "store", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Oranienburger Straße 23, Berlin"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.52491329999999,
               "lng" : 13.395693
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/school-71.png",
         "id" : "4acfe8ffaeb4c678798e77e07984689c15b784ab",
         "name" : "Bikram Yoga Berlin-Mitte",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1520,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108007290164599617928/photos\"\u003eBikram Yoga Berlin-Mitte\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAA9Sd9-6NDGGWc4A3el4d3C83_WRcPKoz4ydOh1A-WLWOMGtpB1hANbclW-GOSFoA1m4aWgajAv5bmH9Trqpul50eowk6p8AzJ8NOiWadQQdXZn7z98ya4HyLs0dcnUfFUEhCBDRuSuH0SwqOmhAXnl2NHGhSt0WyYvrwaQR6s_b1XzxMKLcTehQ",
               "width" : 2048
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJW5xcuuFRqEcRI_Xz3DYB5AI",
         "rating" : 4.6,
         "reference" : "CnRrAAAA53wNtVGPk6dmsw_IQaLtchB2O_16J7MC7x6w8kEP1ZIq5wFiUXiJl44IEz4Z46SFrId_3FrIH7m3xaJYm3a4cq5RkwzY9NPRrJW9B404cP-K-1iXfBPy9WUB6QW_TAD7OkwLctrNxeY4qeqWxWCQCxIQTyK-eqjiXOzx04uF8MR_8BoU0-Qi8RsaCTNC2ZsQYBCafUwjnUs",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "gym", "health", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Krausnickstraße 23, Berlin"
      }, (...)
```

How is that possible? Is that a "feature"? Is there a way to get all kind of establishements that are nearby a given location using Google Places API?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the following announcement of Google:

> Warning: The implementation for types in text search requests is
>   changing. The types parameter is deprecated as of February 16, 2016,
>   replaced by a new type parameter which only supports one type per
>   search request. Additionally, the establishment, place_of_worship,
>   food, health, general_contractor and finance types will no longer be
>   supported as search parameters (however these types may still be
>   returned in the results of a search). Requests using the deprecated
>   features will be supported until February 16, 2017, after which all
>   text searches must use the new implementation.

However, the same problem occurs if querying with no type filter at all compared to a type filter set to type=restaurant.